# Best way to take code changes from DEV to STAGING to PROD

Tags: git, architecture, devops, staging

I am afraid the question may be a little broad, but I am a little confused about the right way of taking the changes I made in development branch to the staging branch and then to the production branch.

To give you more context, I am developing a web app, and let's say I worked on a new feature (big or small, does not matter), and now I want to apply that code to the staging branch so that I can test it on staging before pushing it to the prod. Now, I can merge the dev branch into staging, but this does not seem to be a good way, because I have a ton of code that is for development only, such as console.logs, or other experimental things commented out, etc., and I don't want to push them into staging, and I don't want to delete them and redo for next time.

So, how can I keep the dev code to dev branch, and add only functional pieces to staging?

I am not sure if I am lacking git knowledge here and if there is a better way of manipulating the branches or it may be a wrong architectural design that I am currently doing?

Answer (score 0):

We have to keep the git branching strategy simple that allow team members to follow easily and consistently.

**Branches and Naming convention**

1. trunk or mainline : It should be the default branch of repository integrating all changes for future releases. (example : master, develop or main)
2. release branch : to create a release( example : release/v1.0, release/v1.1,etc)
3. feature branch : to work on an issue( example : ticket-200, ticket-201, etc)

The default branch should be configured in the github initially. The default branch should not be used for release

**A. How to start work on an issue?**

1. Developer has to create an issue branch of the main branch(master or develop)
2. Developer commit the changes into the issue branch(feature branch).
3. Merge into main branch
   Create a   Pull Request against the default branch. Do code review etc. At this point you have to remove the unnecessary debugging code/logging etc. Let the CD process and code review process complete. Then merge it into default branch

**B. How to make a release?**
When source code in the main branch(default branch) reaches a stable point, a release branch is created. And the release build is deployed in your staging environment for testing.

Comment: Why are you creating a separate release branch? Tags are not enough?

Comment: What if you want to fix a bug in the release branch and re-release from release branch? In this use case, i guess release branch will help us